# Code first Application in Entity framework Reset database.

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I created an code first application in entity framework 5. I added a property  "ParentId" in model class.

This parent id is self reference.

I publish the code and upload to test server. and set some value to parentId column.

The problem is when second time I upload publish code It reset parentId  to null.

I think it recreated the parentId column and set its value to default i.e. null.

Kindly let me know to avoid this.

Comment: Did your try local server? Perhaps you have set `DbContext` initializer such as `DropCreateDatabaseAlways<>` that re-creates the database every time you run the application. Without overriding `Seed()` method, the database will be empty.
How have you set values of `ParentID`, using the database GUI or from your application using EF?

Answer (score 0):

exite two method called dropcreatedatabasealways which eliminates your data base and create each time you run the app. createdatabaseifnotexists only creates the basis of data if it has been created but also can create a method to call your dbcontext inicializer to start the app when the data base is creea is removed and inserted into the data defining method.

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx